# Monitoring my personal web traffic behind NTLM-authenticated proxy

Tags: networking, network-monitoring, ntlm

At my office, I'm regularly using more than the recommended bandwidth per month. This isn't a big deal since it's a soft cap, but I do get monthly emails asking me to justify my usage. As I understand it, my replies are compared against ICT's logs  to see if they're plausible. So if I claim my usage is primarily from uploading some huge archives to google drive, they'd check if the majority of the usage was actually to that domain.

The thing is, I'm not always very sure what my major usage is, since my login access is used for multiple devices (a PC running windows, a laptop running Arch, a raspberry Pi running Arch ARM, and several other machines which aren't important for the purposes of this question). On my own laptop, I run vnstat and darkstat (they overlap, but I'm just testing it out). vnstat is good for total usage, darkstat I'm trying out because it's per-IP.

This worked well when I was testing it out at home, but fails pretty hard in my office environment because we connect via proxy here. So by far the biggest bandwidth user on my machine is the proxy IP address, rather than the 'real' services which I'm connecting to. I connect to the through cntlm (to automate the authentication) running on each individual machine.

What options do I have to monitor my traffic usage behind a proxy? All the machines connect to a single router (which does no routing, it just operates as an AP and the office's network is in a LAN port not a WAN port) which is under my control, if that helps. A per-machine tool (like darkstat) is also fine because I can just sum numbers up easily.

One possibility I haven't been able to make headway on is to have my own proxy server (squid perhaps) running. I already do this at home, but I haven't been able to get squid to authenticate with my office proxy NTLM (which is why I'm now using cntlm).

Comment: NTLM is just a login method – you can't "connect through NTLM", that's not a thing. Do you mean connecting through a proxy server that _uses_ NTLM authentication?

Comment: Sorry yes, that's what I meant, hence the line in the 3rd para about proxy IP. Will edit now.